# How to Strikethrough and clear strikethrough in the Listview

Tags: android, listview, strikethrough

I'm developing simple shopping list application. As I need code to make strike-through when item is clicked for the first time and later clear the strike-through when the item in the listview is clicked once again..

I'm able to find the code showing how to create strikethrough or clear strikethrough when onItemClickListener is performed individually.

I want the code for onItemClickListener - first when item is clicked, the item need to get strikeoff later when the strike-off item is clicked again the strikethrough needs to be cleared.
Hope you got my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you storing the list items? If you are storing it in the database, you can have an additional field may be boolean to indicate the strike through and update it when clicked (in onItemClickListener) and use it to strike off and clear.

Comment: Yes, I'm storing the list items in the database. Can you please edit your answer with the sample code so that I would be clear about my question.

Comment: Should be simple enough. You can try out. In the database table, add a field called let's say is_stricken which is of type INTEGER. And default value will be 0. Whenever an item is clicked, update the field to 1 and apply strike through. When clicked again, update the field to 0 and clear strike through. Let me know if you have any problem with implementation.